# Comparing two images with corr2 function

Tags: matlab

I'm dealing with recognition of traffic signs, I'm trying to compare two images with `corr2` function on Matlab, it is not giving good results sometimes, I am using a threshold to find best images among template images. But sometimes it evaluate wrong image. I want to improve results of `corr2` function by pre-processing methods. Which method should I follow?

```
temp=[];
for i=1:10
    res=sprintf('%d.png',i)
    yol=fullfile('cember\taslak_cember\',res);  
    a=imread(yol);
    b=imread('30_1.png');
    a=rgb2gray(a);
    b=rgb2gray(b);
    a=im2bw(a,0.4);
    b=im2bw(b,0.4);
    c=corr2(a,b);
    temp=[temp c];
end
max(temp)
`
```

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to return the template that best match your image based on the corr2 function. If that is what you intend then your code is correct. If for some reason the returned template is not the best it may be due to several factors such as different contrasts, luminosity or other. You should think of performing some pre-processing before using the corr2 function. Maybe a imhistmatch can help

Comment: What do you mean by wrong correlation? And what would be a best match? And what is an end of a function? Please improve the question.